# How to end this kind of loop(while) in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot figure it out how to end this loop :(

```
import random

class Enemy:
    life = 300
    print ('Player 1 your life is ' + str(life) + ' hp' )

    def bonusdmg(self):
        bondmg=random.randrange(40,51)
        print('congratz u made ' + str(bondmg)+' bonus dmg')
        self.life-=bondmg
    def attack(self):
        ad1=random.randrange(50,81)
        print(str(ad1) + 'dmg')
        print('ouch')
        self.life -=ad1
    def attack2(self):
        ad2=random.randrange(60,90)
        print(str(ad2) + 'dmg')
        print('arghhh')
        self.life -=ad2
    def attack3(self):
        ad3=random.randrange(100,111)
        print(str(ad3) + 'dmg')
        print('tsshaaah')
        self.life -=ad3

    def heal(self):
        hp=random.randrange(40,51)
        print ('No more potions')
        self.life +=hp
        print(str(hp) + ' hp have been restored')

    def checkLife(self):
        if self.life <=0:
            print('Your enemy is dead')
        else:
            print(str(self.life) + "hp life left")

class Enemy2:
    life = 300
    print ('Player 2 your life is ' + str(life) + ' hp' )

    def bonusdmg(self):
        bondmg=random.randrange(40,51)
        print('congratz u made ' + str(bondmg)+' bonus dmg')
        self.life-=bondmg
    def attack(self):
        ad1=random.randrange(50,81)
        print(str(ad1) + 'dmg')
        print('ouch')
        self.life -=ad1
    def attack2(self):
        ad2=random.randrange(60,90)
        print(str(ad2) + 'dmg')
        print('arghhh')
        self.life -=ad2
    def attack3(self):
        ad3=random.randrange(100,111)
        print(str(ad3) + 'dmg')
        print('tsshaaah')
        self.life -=ad3

    def heal(self):
        hp=random.randrange(40,51)
        print ('No more potions')
        self.life +=hp
        print(str(hp) + ' hp have been restored')

    def checkLife(self):
        if self.life <=0:
            print('Your enemy is dead')
        else:
            print(str(self.life) + "hp life left")

enemy2 = Enemy2()
enemy1 = Enemy()
while 1:
    turn = 1
    if turn ==1:
        while 1:
            print('Player 1 is your turn !')
            bonus=str(random.randrange(1,6))
            player_move=input('Player1 choose your attack !')
            if player_move =='a':
                enemy1.attack()
                enemy1.checkLife()
                turn +=1
                break
            if player_move =='s':
                enemy1.attack2()
                enemy1.checkLife()
                turn +=1
                break
            if player_move == 'd':
                enemy1.attack3()
                enemy1.checkLife()
                turn +=1
                break
            if enemy1.life <=0:
                break
            if bonus=='2':
                enemy1.bonusdmg()

    if turn ==2:
        while 1:
            print('Player 2 is your turn !')
            bonus=str(random.randrange(1,6))
            player_move=input('Player2 choose your attack !')
            if player_move =='a':
                enemy1.attack()
                enemy1.checkLife()
                turn -=1
                break
            if player_move =='s':
                enemy1.attack2()
                enemy1.checkLife()
                turn -= 1
                break
            if player_move == 'd':
                enemy1.attack3()
                enemy1.checkLife()
                turn -=1
                break
            if enemy1.life <=0:
                break
            if bonus=='2':
                enemy1.bonusdmg()
```

Comment: How *should* it end?  I mean, in words -- what do you want to be the exit condition?

Comment: Whats the difference between the classes Enemy and Enemy2. Looks a bit redundant

Comment: @DanielJimenez: It's a mistake, but he did that because he's using class variables instead of instance variables. For example, he should be setting self.life in the \_\_init\_\_ method instead of assigning life in the class definition.

Comment: @SteveS Yeah that's what I though

Comment: This question probably would have been a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SteveS It sounds to me like the code isn't working as intended.  Code that does not work as intended is absolutely off-topic on [codereview.se].  Please read the [Code Review help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before recommending this Stack Exchange site to other users.

Comment: It sounds to me like this question is very unclear so I have no idea if it is working or not. With a bit better description about what it does, and some assurance that it actually does what it is supposed to do, it could be a better fit for Code Review.

Comment: You have nested `while` loops. Which one is getting "stuck"?

Answer (score 2):

You can try breaking the loop once a certain condition is satisfied. For example, try it like this:

```
# in while loop

if condition_is_true:
    break
```

Otherwise, you'll need to specify a condition within the declaration of your while loop. I suggest this technique because it does not close your program. It can execute the code below your loop as well, if you have any.

```
while condition_is_true:
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up a lot of this, some notes at bottom.

```
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.life = 300
        print('%s your life is %d hp' % (self, self.life))
        self.enemy = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player %d" % self.num

    def bonusdmg(self):
        bondmg=random.randrange(40,51)
        print('congratz u made %d bonus dmg' % bondmg)
        self.deal_damage(bondmg)

    def attack(self):
        ad1=random.randrange(50,81)
        print('You attack for %d dmg -- ouch' % ad1)
        self.deal_damage(ad1)

    def attack2(self):
        ad2=random.randrange(60,90)
        print('You attack for %d dmg -- arghhh' % ad2)
        self.deal_damage(ad2)

    def attack3(self):
        ad3=random.randrange(100,111)
        print('You attack for %d dmg -- tsshaaah' % ad3)
        self.deal_damage(ad3)

    def heal(self):
        hp=random.randrange(40,51)
        print ('No more potions')
        self.life += hp
        print('%d hp have been restored' % hp)

    def checkEnemyLife(self):
        if self.enemy.life <=0:
            return "%s is dead" % self.enemy
        else:
            return "%s has %d hp left" % (self.enemy, self.enemy.life)



    # New
    def take_damage(self, amt):
        print('%s takes %d dmg' % (self, amt))
        self.life -= amt

    # New
    def deal_damage(self, amt):
        self.enemy.take_damage(amt)
        print(self.checkEnemyLife())

    # New
    def handle_action(self, player_move):
        if player_move =='a':  self.attack()
        if player_move =='s':  self.attack2()
        if player_move == 'd': self.attack3()

        bonus=str(random.randrange(1,6))
        if bonus==2:    # Fixed this
            self.bonusdmg()


    # New
    def turn(self):
        print("")
        player_move = raw_input("%s it's your turn!  Choose your attack! " % self)
        self.handle_action(player_move)

    # New
    def won(self):
        return (self.enemy.life <= 0)


player1 = Player(1)
player2 = Player(2)
player1.enemy = player2
player2.enemy = player1

# Enemy class
# life as attribute
# raw_input
# string formatting



turn = 1    # Moved this
run_game = True
while run_game:
    if turn == 1:
        player1.turn()
        if player1.won():
            print("Player 1 wins")
            run_game = False
            break
        turn += 1

    elif turn == 2:
        player2.turn()
        if player2.won():
            print("Player 2 wins")
            run_game = False
            break
        turn -= 1
```

- Made both `Enemy` classes a single `Player` class, `player1` and `player2` are instances of the same class.
- Gave each `Player` instance a reference to their enemy, so they don't deal damage to themselves anymore.
- Created a bunch of methods that help stream line your main game loop
- Improved printing using string formatting (`%`) operator.
- Changed `input` to the safer `raw_input`
- `life` is now an instance attribute instead of a class attribute
- A of other, smaller changes

Answer (score 0):

Although your code has many mistakes,I think the infinite loop you are referring is in the inner loop

```
turn = 1
if turn ==1:
    while 1: #this cause a problem, how are you going to exit this loop?
        #rest of the code
```

You never change `turn = 2` therefore the if statement `turn == 1` is always `True`. You need to find a place to make `turn = 2`  so the second player can move. This however will not solve all your issues.